# Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

Suddenly got this error on a working code.
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
How to get this fixed? Thanks!
JavaScript error: resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionStore.jsm, line 1325: uncaught exception: 2147746065
1599825385642   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 44745
1599825385691   Marionette      WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
1599825406958   Marionette      INFO    Stopped listening on port 44745
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
1599825410215   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile05D3jw"
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
Running without a11y support!